# Use micrometer timer with manual counter increment

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-micrometer

I have a KafkaListener which receives messages containing a list of objects.

```
@KafkaListener(
    id = "dataConsumer",
    topics = "data.topic",
    groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}",
    containerFactory = "dataKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void consumeData(DataContainer message) {
    List<Data> data = message.getList();
    ...
}
```

The list of objects can vary in size so the metrics for each message may not be useful.

I can get the timer metrics for this method by going to `/actuator/metrics/spring.kafka.listener?tag=name:dataConsumer-0` but the count is for the message not the list of elements in the message. How can I switch this metric or make a similar metric for the time and count of the data elements in the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register your own `Meter` with the `MeterRegistry` - refer to the [Micrometer Documentation](https://micrometer.io/).